# C - pointer values change after return from recursion

Tags: c, recursion

the values of fileB and entry->d_name changes after the recursion call( backup(fileB,entry->d_name, archive_file)), why ? and how do I fix this ? thanks in advance!

```
else if(S_ISDIR(h.kind))
{
    printf("\nits a directory #######\n");
    struct dirent* entry = NULL;
    DIR* dir = opendir(h.name);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("Directory couldn't be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        printf("\n %s ********** \n %s ******* \n\n" , entry->d_name,fileB );
        if (strcmp(".", entry->d_name) != 0 && strcmp("..", entry->d_name) != 0) {
            printf("before recursion    entry= %s   ,  fileB= %s \n",entry->d_name,fileB);
            backup(fileB,entry->d_name, archive_file);
            printf("after recursion     entry= %s   ,  fileB= %s \n",entry->d_name,fileB);
        }
    }

    if (closedir(dir)) {
        printf("close dir error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say anything specific.

Comment: The manual page says: "On success, `readdir()` returns a pointer to a `dirent` structure. (This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to `free()` it.)", that sounds relevant but it's hard to say for sure without the full code.

Answer (score 0):

First in your backup function, you should change the arguments for `const char* xxx`. Because you do not intend to modify those. Hence, you are going to create a new char[] or char* in your function :

```
char tmp[]; //you might have to give tmp specific size, use strlen()
strcpy(tmp, path);
strcat(tmp, "/");
strcat(tmp, fileB);
```

Not sure if it will solve your problem, but it might.